# Appcenter ms Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center-distribute, appcenter

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
I updated my proyect to gradle 8.0, androidGradlePluginVersion = '8.1.0'
it asked to update java version

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
```

AS works fine

We are using Appcenter ms to distribute the builds but its not compiling the builds with this upgrated

Getting this error from Appcenter

```
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/11.0.19-7/x64/Contents/Home
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

Any ideas how handle it? we are already set the Environment variables with java 11
[image]

Comment: Have the same question but couldn't figure out the solution though. However, in dev azure pipeline I was able to figure out how to set java 17 which is under advance collapsable under gradle build task. Not certain how to set in app center though(for a different project)

Comment: @SamReyes take a look at my answer, I use app center and I ran into the same error as well and I was able to fix it by changing app center environment variable

Answer (score 6):

I got he same error in app center.

I fixed it by changing the Environment variables `JAVA_HOME`

from

`$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)`

to

`$(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)`.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me as suggested by Not A Programmer. Hope it helps

[image]

Comment: should I support JAVA 17 in my code?

`compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }`